# H2 On Blog/Article Page Gets Assigned a Class

Tags: css, blogs

When I add an H2 to a blog, I noticed there is a spacing issue. I inspected the page and for some reason H2s on blog/article pages get assigned their own class (.searchresults h2).

This does not happen for other headings such as H1, H3, etc…

I am not sure where the “searchresults” class came from, so I don’t want to make custom changes to the “.searchresults h2” element style.

I have thought about adding a new element style to the custom css section, such as:
".searchresults single-post h2", but not sure if that is the best approach or would even work.

Any suggestions on how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What blog? What are you using? This is not nearly enough information to help you. Please read [how to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: This is on a WordPress site, but seemed to be a question that should not be asked on the WordPress Stackexchange.

Comment: Why not ask on WP StackExchange? I would edit your initial question to include this is a WP site and if you are using a theme, what theme that is.

Answer (score 0):

> I inspected the page and for some reason H2s on blog/article pages get
>   assigned their own class

If your blog software is producing:

```
<h2 class="searchresults">
```

and all you want is `<h2>`.

You can run the following javascript:

```
[... document.querySelectorAll('h2.searchresults')].forEach((heading2) => {

  heading2.classList.remove('searchresults');

});
```

Then all the `<h2 class="searchresults">` will revert to `<h2>`.